# Read httpRequest on Angular 4 application oninit method

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have two client application. 1. Dot Net Client 2. Angular Application. Based on user authentication, i am redirecting the client application URL with authentication token at HTTP request. I can able to read the token using the .net application at page load.

```
var response = GetUserID(request);
Public String GetUserID(HttpRequest req)
{
    var UserID = req.ServerVariables.Get("HTTP_USER_ID");     
    if(UserID== NULL)
        return "Header not found. Invalid User"
    else
        return UserID;
}
```

I am not able to get the same request token in angular 4 application component's onint method. I have gone through many articles but couldn't achieve this. How can I get the HTTP request token on angular component onint.

Thanks.

Comment: That's a wrong way of doing it. You can use canActivate function in your route path and write this logic inside that function. If a user isn't authorized the component should not be rendered at all.

Comment: Yes accept thanks Prachi. but how do i get the httprequest token in typescript file.

Comment: You have to call the authorization/ authentication API from Angular and then create the logic on API's response.

Comment: Actually we have authentication logic through TAM group(WebSeal). When user hit the URL, TAM access verified by another application & redirects happens to our Angular APP.

Comment: When it redirects happens to Angular app, how it carry the userId/token ? I mean, the redirect url should contain userId/token